# How can I release memory from TabBarView when I'm navigating to views Swift

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, memory, release

I have a TabBarView and I noticed that when I'm changing views the memory that it has remains and the new view memory add it to to old.

I've tried to reduce it (the memory in every view) by changing all my variables to lazy and it worked for each view separately and now I don't have very high as I had to energy impact section. But the problem with views still remains (I get memory warning after a little navigation to the views)

I have 4 tabs:

- First with tableView
- Second with collectionView
- Third with a Map
- And The last one 3 collectionViews

From my search I understood that I have to do something with viewDidDisappear or Unload

Comment: You could handle the memory warning and unload anything that can be recreated.

Comment: How can i unload a collectionview for example

Comment: The collection view itself can't be using that much memory, are you loading a lot of data or images? What is it that taking it all up?

Comment: @JamesP yes approximatly 280 images

Comment: That could be the problem, make sure you only load them as necessary and delete them/save them to disk when the memory gets too high.